# TextJoin with results from multiple columns

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to replace the **"interacted with you!"** text in my formula with the text in **E$2:E$24** where **M$2:M$24=$B2**, and to only include this text when there is a cell where $B2=M$2:M$24

Essentially, I want the text for **Player1 T0Concatenate** to say

```
@Player1
 You have woken up from a drunken stupor, you have 10 :coin: and :green_square::green_square::green_square::green_square::green_square::green_square::green_square::green_square::green_square::green_square: hp. You belong to no team and are located at the **Tavern**.

In your area you :eye: 
@Player1
@Player2
@Player3
@Player4
@Player5
@Player6
@Player7
@Player8
@Player9
@Player10
@Player11
@Player12
@Player13
@Player14
@Player15
@Player16
@Player17
@Player18
@Player19
@Player20
@Player21
@Player22
@Player23

You were targeted! :dart:
@Player2 used Light attack on you!
@Player3 used Light attack on you!
```

My current formula returns:

```
@Player1
 You have woken up from a drunken stupor, you have 10 :coin: and :green_square::green_square::green_square::green_square::green_square::green_square::green_square::green_square::green_square::green_square: hp. You belong to no team and are located at the **Tavern**.

In your area you :eye: 
@Player1
@Player2
@Player3
@Player4
@Player5
@Player6
@Player7
@Player8
@Player9
@Player10
@Player11
@Player12
@Player13
@Player14
@Player15
@Player16
@Player17
@Player18
@Player19
@Player20
@Player21
@Player22
@Player23

@Player2 interacted with you!
@Player3 interacted with you!
```

I feel like I have just been staring at my problem for too long! Does anyone know a way to solve this?

Currently, I am using the formula

```
=Concatenate(char(10),"@",B2,char(10)," You ",E2,", you have ",G2," :coin: and ",J2," hp.",IF(L2=""," You belong to no team",CONCATENATE(" You belong to team ",L2))," and are located at the **",K2,"**.",IF(H2="","",Concatenate(char(10),char(10),"In your :school_satchel: you find: ",char(10),H2)),char(10),char(10),"In your area you :eye: ",char(10),"@",ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN(concatenate(char(10),"@"),TRUE,IF(K$2:K$24=K2,B$2:B$24))),char(10),char(10),"@",ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN(concatenate(" interacted with you!",char(10),"@"),TRUE,IF(M$2:M$24=$B2,B$2:B$24,"")))," interacted with you!",char(10))
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1f6IzQ83w7lDajcRmAp6iOFaorl1xNMv7PIE1X1fFfoE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Please ask clear questions with including: define your input (format? datatype?), define desired output. Provide examples. (Live sheets is better than inline image. Others are not good.) Please consult guide on [minimal viable examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as needed.

Comment: What is the desired output? It looks to me as if it is already working

Comment: I'd like to switch the "interacted with you text!" with the data in cells E$2:E$24 where M$2:M$24=$B2

Basically want the output to say that Player2 used Light attack on Player 1 and that Player3 used Light attack on Player 1.

Comment: Only for row 2, the other rows should skip the targeting section.

Comment: is there a mirror in the tavern ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a formula that works for me:

```js
=Concatenate(char(10),"@",$B2,char(10),"You ",E2,", you have ",G2," :coin: and ",J2," hp.",IF(L2=""," You belong to no team",CONCATENATE(" You belong to team ",L2))," and are located at the **",K2,"**.",IF(H2="","",Concatenate(char(10),char(10),"In your :school_satchel: you find: ",char(10),H2)),char(10),char(10),"In your area you :eye: ",char(10),"@",ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN(concatenate(char(10),"@"),TRUE,IF(K$2:K$24=K2,$B$2:$B$24))),char(10),join(char(10),unique(arrayformula(if(($M$2:$M=$B$2)*(isblank($M$2:$M)=false),"You were targeted!",)))),join(char(10), unique(arrayformula(if(($M$2:$M=$B$2)*(isblank($M$2:$M)=false),"@"&$B$2:$B&" "&vlookup(value(left($D$2:$D$24,1)), Stats!$A$2:$D,2)&" on you!",)))))
```

Output:

```
"
@Player1
You have woken from a drunken stupor, you have 10 :coin: and :green_square::green_square::green_square::green_square::green_square::green_square::green_square::green_square::green_square::green_square: hp. You belong to no team and are located at the **Tavern**.

In your area you :eye: 
@Player1
@Player2
@Player3
@Player4
@Player5
@Player6
@Player7
@Player8
@Player9
@Player10
@Player11
@Player12
@Player13
@Player14
@Player15
@Player16
@Player17
@Player18
@Player19
@Player20
@Player21
@Player22
@Player23

You were targeted!
@Player2 used Light Attack on you!
@Player3 used Light Attack on you!
"
```

---

`Stats` sheet:

[image: ex]

Answer (score 0):

try in row 1:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"T0Concatenate"; TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(IF(B2:B="",,"@"&B2:B&"×You "&E2:E&", you have "&G2:G&" :coin: and "&J2:J&" hp. You belong to "&
 IF(L2:L="", "no ", )&"team"&IF(L2:L="",, " "&L2:L)&" and are located at the **"&K2:K&"**.××"&
 IF(H2:H="",,"In your :school_satchel: you find: ×"&H2:H&"××")&
 "In your area you :eye:"&REGEXREPLACE(IFNA(VLOOKUP(K2:K, TRIM(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(QUERY({ROW(B2:B), "×@"&B2:B, K2:K&"¤"}, 
 "select max(Col2) where not Col3 starts with '¤' group by Col1 pivot Col3"),,9^9)), "¤")), 2, 0)), " ?×@\b"&B2:B&"\b ?", )&"××"&
 IFNA("You were targeted! :dart:"&VLOOKUP(B2:B, TRIM(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(QUERY({ROW(B2:B), "×@"&B2:B&" "&VLOOKUP(B2:B&"/"&LEFT(D2:D24,1), Stats!A2:D, 2, 0)&" on you!", M2:M&"¤"}, 
 "select max(Col2) where not Col3 starts with '¤' group by Col1 pivot Col3"),,9^9)), "¤")), 2, 0))&
 IFNA(VLOOKUP(Turns!B2:B, TRIM(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(QUERY({ROW(Turns!B2:B), "×@"&Turns!M2:M&" interacted with you!", Turns!B2:B&"¤"}, 
 "select max(Col2) where not Col3 starts with '¤' and not Col2 contains '×@ interacted' group by Col1 pivot Col3"),,9^9)), "¤")), 2, 0))), "×", CHAR(10)))})
```

[image]

### [demo sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tvfVwN0ORJev66fpBGRkczgLtxr9K2nVXcwH5oXnUoU/edit#gid=1774718872)